# Set Custom Keyboard with images in objective c in Portrait and landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, autolayout

I am making an app in which I am making my own custom keyboard in objective c.

I am referring to [this app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rage-faces-keyboard/id924790727?mt=8)

So I want to have images like scrolling in a view.

I have taken a scroll view and put all images in it and it is working fine in portrait mode but for landscape mode, when I set it through auto layout, scrolling doesn't work or the view's are not getting set properly.

So please anyone can guide me on this.

Is it better to use collection view with auto layout?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A collection view would be a far better option than a scrollView. With the scrollview you have to do a lot of things manually, whereas the collectionView as them already implemented.

Scrollviews and auto layout are not that compatible :)

If you do still want to go with the scrollView, you need to update your constraints on orientation change.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateIntrinsicConstraints) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)updateIntrinsicConstraints {
    [self.widthConstraint setConstant:CGRectGetWidth(self.superview.frame)];
    [self.heightConstraint setConstant:CGRectGetHeight(self.superview.frame))];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

In my example, I assumed you would like the scrollView to fill it's parent. If this is not the case you will need to use the appropriate values to suit your case.

Using the collectionView on the other hand, you would not have to change the constraints on orientation change, it is a far cleaner solution.

If you need more help, just let me know

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, you are right. I did it with collectionview. It is far more easier than this... I'll try for this also. +1 for this...